# Rest WS, register with WSO2 IS SSO

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

Can we create a ServiceProvider and register for any RestFul WS, not for the WebApp with jsp, html etc..

Have tried, configuring, my RestWS, localhost:8080/EmpId

It penetrates and gets me response, is there a correct way to archive it?

Edit:

```
@POST
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response postMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "POST:Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
```

There is a postMethod which is listening,

 URL: `http://localhost:8080/{param}`
Note: `There is no login page`.
Can this url be secured as ServiceProvider with WSO2..?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: @Bhathiya have edited the question, is it making clear.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to secure your REST API?

Comment: @Bhathiya, yes exactly...! Can you provide some sample links..!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to secure your REST APIs, the best choice is [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/). Other than security, APIM also provides features such as request throttling, analytics, and many other features to easily manage your APIs.

You can find latest documents [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Getting+Started). Feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

[WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/) is the cloud offering of the same product. You can sign up for it for free.

Comment: That looks great, still, is there a possibility to wire it only using WSO2IS?

Comment: In that case, you'll have to write a lot of code. Basically, you'll have to write what APIM has already written to talk with IS. (APIM has IS features installed.)

Comment: Is that the code to redirect?, cz when I look into the Travelocity example, there is this FILTER , does it to communicate with IS(correct me if I am wrong). Can't we replace the filter as some Java client to do the same?

Comment: Well, the Travelocity is a sample webapp to show how SSO works, and that's for webapps. If you need to secure REST APIs, what you can use is OAuth2. If you want to login to your webapp with SSO and then call your REST APIs with OAuth2, that's also possible with `saml2bearer` grant type of API Manager. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Exchanging+SAML2+Bearer+Tokens+with+OAuth2+-+SAML+Extension+Grant+Type

Comment: I really can't use API Manager, direct commute with IS is the requirement...!! :) Because, I have only REST Client to access, I dont have a webapp

Comment: different microservices has to be enabled with sso.. is the requirement using IS.

Comment: can I use the OAuth2ValidationService provided by wso2, to manually the token generated by some java client?